# The project file 'x.csproj' cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I'm trying to create a new WCF Service Application in Visual Studio 2010. When filling in the name and pressing 'Ok', I get the following message:

> The project file 'x.csproj' cannot be opened. The project type is not
>   supported by this application.

I've found on the internet that the problem can be solved by removing the text in the .csproj file between the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` tags. The problem is, I can't even create the problem.

Also, running the command `devenv.exe /resetskippkgs` in the Visual Studio Command Prompt didn't work out for me.

I've installed Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft Web Developer 2010 Express.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know :/ Could the cause be that VS2010 is the professional edition and WD is the express edition?

Comment: Could you add a reference to the link you _found on the internet_?

Comment: Amongst a lot of site, this one: http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/workitem/1679

Comment: Currently downloading Visual Studio 2010 Express to see if installing that makes any difference.

Comment: VS Express couldn't be started without installing the SP1 (again). This doesn't fit on my computer and is therefore not done.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this question.  Your "I've found on the internet that the problem can be solved by removing the text in the .csproj file between the  tags" led me to the solution to the inability to open a project.

In Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio Express 2015 the error shown in the GUI was "Unsupported -  This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them."  The corresponding error in the UpgradeLog.htm file was "The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information."

Was able to open (and then build) project by removing in a text editor from the .csproj file a portion of the text in between these tags:

```
<ProjectGuid> </ProjectGuid>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a portion of the text in between these tags". What portion? Tried removing it and still got errors.